# c++ cli comparing hexadecimal bytes from a file not working

Tags: c++, windows, file, c++-cli, byte

I have this file called ab.exe it contains this in hexadecimal

0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000BBAAE8CAFDFFFF83C408000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054AAE8CAFDFFFF83C40800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000AAE8CAFDFFFF83C4088D000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I have this code in c++ that is suppose to detect if a string of hexadecimal is in a file or not and if it is add it to the list box.

```
array<Byte>^ target1 = { 0xAA,0xE8,0xCA,0xFD,0xFF,0xFF,0x83,0xC4,0x08,0x8D };
array<Byte>^ target2 = { 0x54,0xAA,0xE8,0xCA,0xFD,0xFF,0xFF,0x83,0xC4,0x08 };
array<Byte>^ target3 = { 0xBB,0xAA,0xE8,0xCA,0xFD,0xFF,0xFF,0x83,0xC4,0x08 };


int matched1 = 0;
int matched2 = 0;
int matched3 = 0;
FileStream^ fs2 = gcnew FileStream(line, FileMode::Open, FileAccess::Read, FileShare::ReadWrite);

int value;
do
{
    value = fs2->ReadByte();
    if (value == target1[matched1]) {
        matched1++;
    }
    else
        matched1 = 0;

    if (value == target2[matched2]) {
        matched2++;
    }
    else
        matched2 = 0;

    if (value == target3[matched3]) {
        matched3++;
    }
    else
        matched3 = 0;

    if(matched1 == target1->Length)
    {
        listBox1->Items->Add(line + "1");

    }

    if(matched2 == target2->Length)
    {
        listBox1->Items->Add(line + "2");

    }

    if(matched3 == target3->Length)
    {
        listBox1->Items->Add(line + "3");

    }
} while (value != -1);

fs2->Close();
```

the problem is that it only adds line + 3 to the list box and not line + 1 or line + 2 to the list box

I do not know why that is because all 3 of the strings are in the file so they all should be added to the list box. for some reason only the last one is being added because I tried just having 2 and the second one got added.can someone show me why they are not all being added to the list box.
thanks

**Update1**

after playing around with it some more it is not the last target that gets added each time, It is the first string that appears in the file that gets added. I stepped through the program using message boxes and what is happening is lets say 54AAE8CAFDFFFF83C408 is the first string to appear in the file then line + 2 will be added, but then for some reason the matched integer for all 3 stop counting they just = 0 the rest of the file. can someone explain to me why that is and how to fix it.

**Update2**

here is the answer to the problem. all I needed to do was just add a matched = 0; after each add to list box command.

```
listBox1->Items->Add(line + "1");
matched1 = 0;

listBox1->Items->Add(line + "2");
matched2 = 0;

listBox1->Items->Add(line + "3");
matched3 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that after the first matching of one pattern (here target3) you read beyond last byte of target3 (because of `matched3++`), this may cause undesired behavior.

Update1:

```
if(matched1 == target1->Length)
{
  matched1 = 0; // pattern matched so reset counter
  ...
}
```

Comment: can you please explain how to fix it. I also added an update to the question